# Does one GRPC channel request generate one more new thread in the GRPC server side?

Tags: grpc

I'm new to GRPC. I want to know that if the server start a new thread to process when a GRPC client start one request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be up to one `Runnable` enqueued to the [Server's executor](http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html#executor-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) for application processing. Each request may generate more than one `Runnable` over time, but only one at a given time. The default executor is an unbounded cached thread pool, so worst-case each request gets its own thread initially, but later requests will generally reuse previous threads.

It is good practice for high QPS services to specify a fixed-sized executor, to avoid excessive number of threads and reduced context switch thrashing.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It would be better if the GRPC itself can set the maximum thread number.